# How do I create a Dictionary of classes, so that I can use a key to determine which new class I want to initialize?

Tags: c#, dictionary, abstract-class

As per the question, how do I create a Dictionary in C# where the key is say, an integer, but the values are classes that I can call the constructor for by using just the value in the Dictionary? Each of the classes are derived from an abstract class, and they take the same parameters, so I feel like I should be able to store the resulting reference to the new class object in a variable of the abstract class type.

That being said, a Dictionary's value set is usually filled with references to objects, not types themselves. As a quick example, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
abstract class BaseObject {

     int someInt;
}

class ObjectA : BaseObject {

    ObjectA (int number) {
        someInt = number;
    }
} 

class ObjectB : BaseObject {

    ObjectB (int number) {
        someInt = number;
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to do the following:

```
Dictionary<int, ???????> objectTypes = new Dictionary<int, ???????>();

objectTypes.Add(0, ObjectA);
objectTypes.Add(1, ObjectB);
```

So I can eventually:

```
BaseObject newObjectA, newObjectB;

newObjectA = new objectTypes[0](1000);
newObjectB = new objectTypes[1](2000);
```

The syntax is probably quite different, but I hope I at least got across what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to implement your own dependancy injection framework, or similar. A Services Container at least.
(not a bad thing to do, though you may wish to look at existing things like Ninject)

Comment: Wow, I had to look up a couple of those terms. My goal, essentially, is to be able to generate instances of classes that can subscribe to an update mechanism through the base. However, I derive a ton of different classes from the base class, and each's constructor is very different.

I don't think it's actually dependency injection because I have each of my classes grabbing what it needs to so I can use the same constructor, I just want to be able to create and use instances of them at runtime so they types of objects generated can be affected by input.

Comment: Ah, it is for a Publisher-Subscriber mechanism (to keep you looking up terms. :-P) 
Your right it is not dependency injection, or a services container. That said, your life may be muchly simplified by using a dependancy injection framework.

Comment: The only issue I've run across (since that's what I did initially) is that I'm running this on an authoritative server framework, and it's been much easier to encapsulate varying bits of authoritative info into appropriate managers, so that I can sync the managers between the clients and the server and then let my runtime-generated classes grab what they need as they need it. That way my networking includes just the syncing of the managers, and command RPCs without any actual information parameters.

Comment: That all being said, can you think of any better way to associate the runtime generation of each type of a derived classes with a primitive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var objectTypes = new Dictionary<int, Func<int, BaseObject>>();
objectTypes[0] = input => new ObjectA(input);
objectTypes[1] = input => new ObjectB(input);

objectTypes[0](1000);
objectTypes[1](2000);
```

Here instead of storing object, I store a Func to generate each concrete object

Comment: This is really interesting, and I hadn't thought of it as an alternative to storing types. Do you know if this is faster than storing types and using the Activator?

Comment: as far as I know, this should be faster than Activator, since it doesn't use reflection

Answer (score 4):

```
Dictionary<int, Type> objectTypes = new Dictionary<int, Type>();

objectTypes.Add(0, typeof(ObjectA));
objectTypes.Add(1, typeof(ObjectB));

var newObjectA = (BaseObject)Activator.CreateInstance(objectTypes[0], new object[] {1000});
```

[Documentation for Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Leaving this here as it is just another way to do it, but Phuong's answer is a much cleaner and customizable approach at compile time.

The key difference is if you want something dynamic at runtime or compile time. If it's all compile time, I suggest the `Func` method. If your types are unknown at compile time, then you will want to use this way as there are many ways to dynamically instantiate a class using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was asking how to do, but Phuong's approach is really interesting as well. Going to have to do some research on functions to determine if using the Activator or Func is the most efficient way.

Comment: @Kyton `Activator.CreateInstance` will probably be slower. `Func` is just a delegate and will end up getting compiled into its own method. I say slower, but that is relative (small milliseconds) as you will probably never notice it depending on where you are using this. Either way, easy to test by looping both 100k times.

Comment: @Kyton The main difference between the approaches is if you needed to dynamically load your types from an assembly at runtime and initialize those. `Func`, you will need to know at compile time.

Comment: AH! That clears it up, thanks for the clarification. So if I were to use some kind of external compiled library that wasn't accessible when I compiled my code, I'd have to use the Activator. But in the case that all the classes and their constructors are defined in the scope that I'm compiling this code in, using Func will work fine (and faster).

Comment: @Kyton Correct. In regards to one of your comments above, it almost sounded like you are doing something dynamic at runtime and this to be driven off of a config file (assuming). One of the overloads for `CreateInstance` takes in a `string`. It will instantiate classes purely off of the namespace and name of the class (namespace might be optional... I forget). EDIT: 1st param is the assembly name.

Comment: For some reason, I didn't think the names in source code even made it into compiled code. Is there some special requirement for a class to be accessible through the Activator by name alone, or are class names stored in compiled code in such a way in C# that they can all be accessed by default like that?

Comment: @Kyton There is a ton of metadata available. That's what allows reflection to work. The only requirement is that the Assembly that contains the class you want to instantiate needs to be loaded first.